# Cargo Capacity of an Interwar Period Military Airship

Tags: airships

In my AH there are large airships which are more advanced than those in our time line, i.e. real history (hereafter known as "OTL"). Country A has invaded country B and B needs to get some 'marines' to the threatened cities quickly (more quickly than marching/driving).

Country a B has good rail network but I'd assume large airships may be slightly quicker to get light infantry/bicycle/motorcycle troops to the threatened area - to be followed up by train-borne heavier troops in slightly slower time.

My question is this: how many troops could a large airship carry? (Obviously they don't need the level of luxury that the passengers in OTL enjoyed.)

Comment: The weight and volume of the troops themselves seems incidental. Your problem is the weight of all their kit, all of their equipment, a pre-packaged one week of the fuel for that equipment, all of their weapons, and one week of the ammunition for those weapons. That's enormous. If you have all that kit and equipment pre-positioned, *then you likely don't need the troops* -- the city's militia, plentifully so equipped, can handle the defense.

Comment: It's unclear what "OTL" means.

Comment: I love the idea of bicycle troops to minimize weight!

Comment: Also none of the bike marines weigh more than 50kg, and are armed with pumpable air rifles and ninja swords.

Comment: actually just reading this which was what prompted me was an early 20th century way to increase infantry mobility https://www.amazon.co.uk/Military-History-Bicycle-Forgotten-Machine-ebook/dp/B08WS3CPPL?msclkid=764ddf70d07011ecba3d7c53c153002a

Comment: Is the idea here for this to be a sort of last-minute improvised thing, or a regular part of the nation's strategic plan? Is there a hanger at the other end? Supplies to supplement the troops? Is the territory in friendly or enemy hands? An air fleet using ammonia as a secondary lifting gas will have better ability to fly to/from less developed locations due to buoyancy control. Paratroopers wouldn't even need to be landed, but could jump from an airship to rapidly deploy. But ammonia has slightly less lift and parachutes add a little more weight.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but it is almost certainly a false assumption that airships would get troops to a rail-served locale faster.  The _maximum_ (short endurance) speed of the _Akron_ was 79 mph, assuming favourable winds.  By the 1930s, trains could comfortably _average_ that speed on well-maintained tracks.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how much in the way of equipment they need to carry with them (ammunition, weapons, food, water etc). But as a guide I would use the US airship Akron:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Akron
This could carry up to 72 tonnes of cargo. This cargo included 5 planes which could be launched and caught in the air. But Assuming the planes weren't carried and the hanger area was modified for troops around 600 at 120kg each including kit and modest supplies could be carried.

I'm not sure if 600 people could be accommodated, but an additional floor might be added at a weight penalty and either the size could be modestly increased or hydrogen could be used instead of (or as well as) the helium which Akron and her sister ship Macon used.

Comment: 600 people are the battallion range, then consisting of 3 or 4 companies of 200 or 150 each, which then have their subdivisions.

Comment: That 120Kg seems light. Doing quick search suggests 45Kg(100lbs) of gear is common with US soldiers. So budgeting 140 Kg per soldier might be more reasonable. Non modest heavy kit apparently is 90Kg per.

Comment: Sure you pays your money and takes your choice. The troops can be transferred but how much kit do they need with them and what is available when they arrive? 73 tonnes and maybe double that with hydrogen...